# Permanently changing default output style

Tags: output-formatting, options, stylesheet

I have read through this discussion several times: [Keeping Quotation Marks in Output](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5585/keeping-quotation-marks-in-output)

Unfortunately, the accepted answer here only works once, at the notebook level. I'd like to permanently change this option (always showing string quotes) for the entire front-end, but somehow I can't get it to work.

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, 
 StyleDefinitions -> 
  Notebook[{Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]], 
    Cell[StyleData["Output"], ShowStringCharacters -> True]}]]
```

seemed like a good shot, but doesn't actually work. Of course, replacing $FrontEnd with EvaluationNotebook[] does work, but only for that notebook. Upsetting!

I also tried directly editing Default.nb and Core.nb, but it caused M to crash on startup.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that editing Core.nb works just fine, as long as you delete the cache information in the .nb file. This solves the problem.